# How do you break rotary craft blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just added Rotary Craft to my 1.4.7 world. I placed a steel shaft, and later tried to break it with my power tool, but it wouldn't break. Was i too impatient or are diamond grade tools not enough to break Rotary craft blocks? How do I break these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power tools aren't recognized by RotaryCraft as pickaxes (RotaryCraft also doesn't recognize things like Thaumcraft's wand of excavation). Use a normal diamond pick and you should be able to break the block.

Comment: Is there a config option or any other way that lets me change that? Not that crafting pickaxes would be a problem, but i would like to reduce mod - specific quirks to a minimum. ..

Comment: @kutschkem Unfortunately not. This is why we need a modding API